# Dynamic capture group name in preg_match()

Tags: php, regex

In PHP, is it possible to create dynamically named capture groups?

For example say I want to parse a dsn into its components. Consider the following:

```
<?php

$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase';

preg_match_all('/host=(?P<host>[^;]+);dbname=(?P<dbname>[^;]+)/', $dsn, $matches);
```

Is it possible to achieve the same result without explicitly defining each capture group's name?

In other words, match pattern `/;|:([^=]+)=([^;]+)/` and use whatever is on the left side of the equals sign as the group's name, and whatever is on the right side as the value.

I am aware I could emulate the desired behavior with something like this:

```
<?php

$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase';

list($engine, $dsn) = explode(':', $dsn);
$result = [];

 while(preg_match('/;?(?P<key>[^=]+)=(?P<val>[^;]+)/', $dsn, $matches)) {
    $result[$matches['key']] = $matches['val'];
    $dsn = str_replace($matches[0], '', $dsn);
}
```

I'm also aware that there are several other ways of achieving this. I'm not looking for a workaround, I'm interested in knowing if dynamically named capture groups are possible, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't possible.

idea of workaround:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase';

if (preg_match_all('~([^;:=]+)=([^;]*)~', $dsn, $matches))
    $result = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

Comment: Now that is a pretty one! I didn't think of using `array_combine()` but it's the perfect tool for the job. Just one correction: there should be `;?` after the opening delimiter to eliminate it from the keys. Otherwise this is just perfect, thanks!

Comment: @Schlaus: indeed I have forgotten the `;`, it is corrected.

Answer (score 2):

No, named capture groups cannot be dynamic. What you've shown is pretty much the only way to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but the one I was afraid I'd get anyway. Vote up for you, but I'll have to accept Casimir's answer since he offered what must be the next best thing. Thanks!

Comment: @Schlaus: I thought of the solution with array_combine too, but didn't post it because you stated in the question that you're not looking for another workaround. Great minds think alike, haha! Glad you found a solution, nonetheless. Cheers!